# Is there any examples for Akka parametric Creators?

Tags: java, java-8, akka

I have some similiar actors and want unify their generated methods. 
I find this example in akka docs but have not any idea how fabricate my actor

```
static class ParametricCreator<T extends MyActor> implements Creator<T> {
@Override public T create() {
  // ... fabricate actor here
}
```

}

then I try do this for test sending creator as parameters

```
private static Creator<MyActor> myCreator = MyActor::new;
public static Props props() {
    return Props.create(myCreator);
}
```

but catch this

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at core.AppContext.initActors(AppContext.java:28)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: erased Creator types are unsupported, use Props.create(actorClass, creator) instead

Sorry for my noob question and bad language but I can`t solve this problem without help.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same problem. Pretty late but maybe help to others. Solution is in error message: **use Props.create(actorClass, creator) instead**.

So:

```
private static Creator<MyActor> myCreator = MyActor::new;
public static Props props() {
    return Props.create(MyActor.class, myCreator);
}
```

You must specify exact type of actor in the creator.